# PHP Print Conditional with another Print

Tags: php, navigation, conditional-statements

I am new to PHP so forgive me if this is not the best way to achieve this goal.  I am creating a sub navigation page and I wish to detect the parent variable and then render out the correct sub navigation for that parent.  Then within that detect the child page the user is on and print an .active class to the sub navigation.

```
<?php print (($primaryNav == 'training') ? '
        <li class="'print (($secondaryNav == 'classes') ? 'active' : '')'">
            <a href="/dev/training.php#classes">Classes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="'print (($secondaryNav == 'calendar') ? 'active' : '')'">
            <a href="/dev/calendar/">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="'print (($secondaryNav == 'instructors') ? 'active' : '')'">
            <a href="/dev/training.php#instructors">Instructors</a>
        </li>
' : ''); ?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of being able to read the code I would do something like this instead:

```
<?php

if ($primaryNav == 'training') {

  $classes = ($secondaryNav == 'classes') ? 'active' : '';
  $calendar = ($secondaryNav == 'calendar') ? 'active' : '';
  $instructors = ($secondaryNav == 'instructors') ? 'active' : '';

?>
<li class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
    <a href="/dev/training.php#classes">Classes</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo $calendar; ?>">
    <a href="/dev/calendar/">Calendar</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo $instructors; ?>">
    <a href="/dev/training.php#instructors">Instructors</a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you.  My apologies for the abomination of php code I created :)

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed of! We all improve over time :) It's all about experience - keep it up!